# How to make ts include year in prepended date?

Tags: time

`ts` can be used to prepend time to a line of text:

```
$ echo "foo bar test" | ts
Dec 06 12:42:16 foo bar test
```

I want to obtain this exact time format, but including the year,

```
2014 Dec 06 12:42:16 foo bar test
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ts.1.html):

```
   The optional format parameter controls how the timestamp is formatted,
   as used by strftime(3). The default format is "%b %d %H:%M:%S". In
   addition to the regular strftime conversion specifications, "%.S" and
   "%.s" are like "%S" and "%s", but provide subsecond resolution (ie,
   "30.00001" and "1301682593.00001").
```

For example:

```
$ echo a  | ts '%F %T'
2014-12-06 23:16:02 a
```

For the particular format requested:

```
$ echo a  | ts '%Y %h %d %H:%M:%S'
2014 Dec 06 23:17:40 a
```

Consult [`man strftime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/strftime.3.html) for the various format specifiers available.